# Having git reformat source on push

Tags: git, formatting, githooks

I'm mastering a development team where everyone worked with Eclipse and the same formatting settings.

Now some of the developers have reasons to switch to other IDEs, which format source code differently. So, when they now push to the git origin repo, git notices a a lot of cosmetic differences. Unfortunately, this is a big problem for some of the developers to get their head around.

Is there a way to get git - maybe by using hooks - to reformat everything on push or preferably commit, so the code in the repo is always formatted IDE independently?

I'm assuming we are not the first team in git-history to have that problem, so I hope there is a prefab solution or at least some best practices.

Comment: Usually, you solve this by configuring all IDEs to use the same formatting. Nowadays, IDEs have quite extensive settings to control the formatting.

Comment: You could have everyone install precommit hooks if there is a tool for your language that works well for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only way to do this reliably is on the server side (client-side hooks are not automatically set up during clone for security reasons, so if you do it on the client side as suggested in one of the comments, each developer has to manually set up that hook once).

There, you can, in theory, manipulate the received updates... but it's a fairly complicated thing to do. The actual *problem*, though, is that once it's done, you have your own, untouched commits locally and there are modified commits on the server – this is asking for trouble. If you were to do a pull/merge now, git would combine the untouched history with the modified history and suddenly you have all of the commits twice.

If you want to make sure only properly formatted code ends up in the repository, it's much easier and causes less problems if you *reject* incorrectly formatted code. This can be fairly annoying in practice, of course, but that's the trade-off you have to decide about.

Suppose you can get your developers to do that local hook setup thing, then a local pre-commit hook will almost certainly be easier to write and cause less hassle in practice – but it can be bypassed in various ways, so there are no ironclad guarantees.

Comment: The project as such uses multiple languages - Java, JS and HTML + a few bash skripts and the odd txt and xml. Rejecting isn't really an option because then everyone would have to manually adjust their code. We have one developer who is very vocal and if things don't look precisely like he thinks they should, he simply will not let anyone else work.

Comment: That's pretty sad, but it changes nothing about what's technically feasible. Either you use local hooks with no guarantee or you reject. Or you create huge amounts of extra work (and potential for mistakes) whenever something is reformatted on the server side – rejecting is actually probably cheaper in the long run than reformatting on the server side.

Comment: PS. a project I know outputs a diff for fixing the formatting whenever a commit is rejected. The rejects are still annoying, though.

Comment: I agree with the above. You are looking at "push is placing under version control" (à la CVS, SVN and their ilk), with `git` it is _commit_ that places stuff under version control. And better make sure everybody is on the same page format-wise. Anything else is inviting untold grief later on.

Comment: We've agreed to use one IDE for each type of project and format according to the same rules per IDE.